# MongoDB / PHP - How to change data type for every occurrence of field in a document

Tags: mongodb, php

I'm trying to learn how to use MongoDB with PHP. I Have built a web application that loads data from database etc. The issue I am having is that when I import my data from a .CSV using MongoDB Compass, by default everything is imported as a string.

[image]

I have also tried to do it using cmd with the following but had no luck;

```
mongoimport --db hddatabase --collection crimes --type csv 
--columnsHaveTypes --fields "CrimeID.string(),CrimeMonth.date(2006-01),CrimeReportedIn.string(),CrimeFallsWithin.string(),CrimeLongitude.double(),CrimeLatitude.double(),CrimeLocation.string(),CrimeLSOACode.string(),CrimeLSOAName.string(), CrimeType.string(), CrimeLastOutcomeCategory.string(), CrimeContext.string()" 
--file C:\Users\01\Desktop\desk\WestCrime.csv
```

I can see how to use the MongoDB Compass GUI to change the value of individual documents manually.. I cannot for the life of my work out how to do this for all documents in a collection. Any help for the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I tried the below based on recommendation and am getting "Could not parse type from header CrimeReporttedIn.string(); 0 documents imported

```
mongoimport --db hddatabase --collection crimes --type csv --fields CrimeReportedIn.string\(\),CrimeFallsWithin.string\(\),CrimeLongitude.double\(\),CrimeLatitude.double\(\),CrimeLocation.string\(\),CrimeLSOACode.string\(\),CrimeLSOAName.string\(\),CrimeType.string\(\),CrimeLastOutcomeCategory.string\(\),CrimeContext.string\(\) --columnsHaveTypes --file C:\Users\01\Desktop\desk\WestCrime.csv
```

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223443/mongoimport-choosing-field-type

Comment: @Mani , I tried to follow the advice on the posted you linked, can you take a look at the post update if possible? thanks